# Can I iteratively update a single column multiple times - in a single statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that I receive as a table-type parameter in my stored procedure (it comes from an excel workbook source, but that's a different story). It has several columns that I need to validate the values against a list of valid values for each column.

Let's say my table `OriginDetails` looks like this (please note that this is just mock data;  I have two such tables with each 8 columns I will be validating) -

```
Origin   | Status     | Priority | ErrMsg
------------------------------------------
Testing  | In Review  | Low      | 
Design   | Initiated  | Medium   | 
Prod     | Declined   | Critical |
```

And, I am validating the values in the columns `Origin`, `Status` and `Priority` against three different lists (actually I am validating the values against data in tables, but for simplicity I hard-coded these values here), and updating the `ErrMsg` column based on my validations -

```
UPDATE OriginDetails 
SET ErrMsg = ErrMsg + '|Invalid Origin' 
WHERE Origin NOT IN ('Pre-Design','Design','Development') 

UPDATE OriginDetails 
SET ErrMsg = ErrMsg + '|Unrecognized Status' 
WHERE Status NOT IN ('In Review','Approved') 

UPDATE OriginDetails 
SET ErrMsg = ErrMsg + '|Priority check failed' 
WHERE Priority NOT IN ('Critical','Medium','High')
```

This is all fine and dandy, works great - but I end up with 16 such update statements for 2 tables together, so I have a really large and ugly block of code (and a lot of duplication also since I have almost identical code for 2 tables).

Is there a way I can actually do all the updates in one single statement for each table?

Something like the below, **except that it should execute each of the conditions instead of only one** -

```
UPDATE OriginDetails
SET ErrMsg = ErrMsg + 
(CASE WHEN Origin NOT IN ('Pre-Design','Design','Development') 
           THEN '|Invalid Origin'
      WHEN Status NOT IN ('In Review','Approved') 
           THEN '|Unrecognized Status'
      WHEN Priority NOT IN ('Critical','Medium','High') 
           THEN '|Priority check failed'
END)
```

Any ideas/direction are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work well (and only require you type the values a single time):

```
UPDATE OriginDetails
SET ErrMsg = ErrMsg + 
    CASE WHEN Origin NOT IN ('Pre-Design','Design','Development') THEN '|Invalid Origin' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN Status NOT IN ('In Review','Approved') THEN '|Unrecognized Status'  ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN Priority NOT IN ('Critical','Medium','High')  THEN '|Priority check'  ELSE '' END
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/028c1/1).

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
UPDATE OriginDetails
SET ErrMsg = ErrMsg + 
(CASE 
WHEN Origin NOT IN ('Pre-Design','Design','Development') and Status NOT IN ('In Review','Approved') and Priority NOT IN ('Critical','Medium','High') 
           THEN '|Invalid Origin|Unrecognized Status|Priority check failed'
WHEN 
Origin NOT IN ('Pre-Design','Design','Development') and Status NOT IN ('In Review','Approved') and Priority IN ('Critical','Medium','High') 
           THEN '|Invalid Origin|Unrecognized Status'


END)
```

you can add all cases as I did.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, I'll test and see how that works - thanks!

Comment: :) hope it works for you, I have similar case for an ERP system to update status of materials according to quality control and quality assurance.

Comment: @AkamOmer -- feel free to review my response -- should help you simplify things as well.  Good luck.

Comment: @sgeddes: thanks, I got it, your answer is much easier, and simpler, It was new for me (Thanks again) using + sign with case I will test it soon.

Comment: @AkamOmer - thank you for your answer, I appreciate your help very much - but I chose sgeddes's answer for it's simpler and shorter.

Comment: @ChaithanyaM: I am also :), mine is just deeper logic, his one is faster and uses available tools which is better.